# Constructing a constexpr std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, constexpr, weak-ptr

According to the `std::weak_ptr` documentation one can construct a `constexpr` `weak_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>
constexpr weak_ptr<int> foo{};
```

However, trying this with clang produces a compilation error complaining that a constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type '`const std::weak_ptr<int>`', which is because `weak_ptr<int>` has a user-provided destructor. (which is does, looking at the libc++ headers)

My question is, is this a libc++ bug, or do `constexpr` `weak_ptr` just make no sense and having the constexpr default constructor is a mistake? Can I expect this to work in the future?

Comment: The destructor of `weak_ptr` is responsible for a deallocation (of the `shared_ptr` control block, which is what a `weak_ptr` hangs on to), so I don't think it can be `constexpr`.

Comment: Please do link to or cite the documentation you're referring to.

Comment: I see in C++14 (the final draft N3290) that the default constructor is `constexpr`. That's baffling to me.

Comment: [Here's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr) the en.cppreference reference.  The C++11 standard lists `constexpr weak_ptr() noexcept;` at §20.7.2.3.1.

Comment: There's some interesting discussion in [DR827](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#827).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is this a libc++ bug

No.

> Do `constexpr` `weak_ptr` just make no sense

Yes.

> having the constexpr default constructor is a mistake?

No. A `constexpr` constructor used on a non-literal type permits [constant initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) for static and thread storage duration variables, which takes place before any dynamic initialization.

This means, for instance, that a global default-constructed `weak_ptr` object is always initialized, and can safely be used in constructors of global objects.

```
// TU 1
namespace foo {
   std::weak_ptr<int> meow;
}

// TU 2
namespace foo {
   extern std::weak_ptr<int> meow;
}

struct C {
    C() { /* can safely use foo::meow here */ }
} c;
```

> Can I expect this [`constexpr` `weak_ptr`] to work in the future?

No.

Comment: I see no defect report about it. Do you know the rationale for the `constexpr` on the default constructor?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Like I said, it permits constant initialization.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, do you know the rationale?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf http://wg21.link/lwg827 "eliminating another unfair advantage of raw pointers"

Comment: Thank you for the added example. The rationale is that the `constexpr` supports a surprising non-obvious initialization order? I don't get it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I think it's like, it makes it easier to avoid a static initialization fiasco in code like T.C.'s example? Otherwise you would have to use some complex singleton construct, or go back to raw pointers.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Yes, but then comes a maintenance programmer who spots the cross-TU reference, and, unaware of this added corner case, uses some time (well say 45 minutes for local build and unit testing) on reimplementing as a fiasco-safe singleton. Win = negative.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I guess you could put a code comment with a link to T.C.'s answer right above it :p

Comment: I mean, even if you think actually using this is not a good practice, the flip side is, if the `constexpr` wasn't there then someone would report it as a defect, since now they are prevented by the standard library from usefully constant initializing their `std::weak_ptr`, right?

Comment: This is one of those, "gosh, I learned something today" answers.

Comment: @T.C. The compiler has permission to use `constexpr` constructors for constant init. makes sense. I just don't agree with you that it makes no sense to have `constexpr weak_ptr`. I have a set of types that are 'mostly' `constexpr` except for a `weak_ptr` member. I would like to have a suite of these objects constructed at compiletime to avoid constant init at startup. Since a `static constexpr` has unlimited lifetime and can not be mutated, I believe it makes sense to omit calling any destructor. That said, I believe you've found the reason, and DR827 pointed out by @md5i seems to corroborate.